# Bayes formula help!

Tags: statistics, bayes-theorem

Suppose a test for diagnosing a certain disease is successful in detecting the disease in $95$% of all persons infected, but it incorrectly diagnoses $4$% of all healthy people as having the serious disease. Suppose also that it incorrectly diagnoses $12$% of all people having another minor disease as having the serious disease. It is known that $2$% of the population has the serious disease, $90$% of the population is healthy, and $8$% has the minor disease.

Use Bayes formula to find the probability that a person selected at random has the serious disease, given that the test indicates that he or she does Use $H$ to represent healthy, $M$ to represent having the minor disease and D to represent having the serious disease.

This is what I've started with and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track because I don't fully understand this:

$5$% diseased people ($100-95$% successful diagnosis), $96$% of healthy people ($100-4$%incorrectly diagnosed), $88$% minor ($100-12$% of people having minor disease)

$P[M | H] 88 \cdot 8=7.04$%

$P[D | H]\ 5 \cdot 2=0.1$%

$P[H | H]\ 96 \cdot 90=86.4$%

$P[D| H]\ = 0.1+86.4+7.04=93.54$%

I don't understand Bayes Formula at all, please explain... am I on the right track?

Comment: This is what I've started with and I'm not sure I I'm on the right track because I don't fully understand this:
5% diseased people (100-95% successful diagnosis), 96% of healthy people (100-4%incorrectly diagnosed), 88% minor (100-12% of people having minor disease)


P[M | H] 88*8=7.04%
P[D | H] 5*2=0.1%
P[H | H] 96*90=86.4%

P[D| H]= 0.1+86.4+7.04=93.54% 

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I have added your comments to the question. It is always better if you add any extra information you write directly to the question and not in the comments. It will help you better. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I won't work the problem completely, but will try to give you a useful way to start.

You know $P(D) = 0.02, P(T|D) = 0.95,$ and $P(N|D^c) = 0.96,$ where
$T$ indicates a  positive test (disease detected) and $N = T^c$ indicates a negative test (no detection). You are asked to find $P(D|T).$

It seems to me that the information about the minor disease is a distraction.

If this is correct, then $P(D|T) = P(D\cap T)/P(T),$ and
you can find $P(D\cap T) = P(D)P(T|D).$ And then
you can find $P(T) = P(D\cap T) + P(D^c\cap T).$

What remains is for you to find $P(D^c\cap T)$ in a manner
somewhat similar to the that used to find $P(D\cap T),$ but using complement rules.

Among the "Related" links in the right-hand margin of this
page, you should find several completed computations of this type.
[This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Drug_testing)
from Wikipedia may also be helpful; let 'User' be $D.$ (This article is not easy to find via
Google using sensible search words because commercial junk takes over their first few pages.)

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose a test for diagnosing a certain disease is successful in detecting the disease in 95% of all persons infected, but it incorrectly diagnoses 4% of all healthy people as having the serious disease. Suppose also that it incorrectly diagnoses 12% of all people having another minor disease as having the serious disease. It is known that 2% of the population has the serious disease, 90% of the population is healthy, and 8% has the minor disease.

The key here is that you have *two* random variables.   There is the *actual* state of the subject, and the *result* of the test.

Let $S$ be the subject's status, $T$ be the test result; each supporting values $H,M,D$ (healthy, minor disease, or serious disease; as suggested).

List what has been told:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(T{=}D \mid S{=}D)&=\phantom{0.95}\\ \mathsf P(T{=}D\mid S{=}H)&=\phantom{0.04}\\ \mathsf P(T{=}D\mid S{=}M)&=\phantom{0.12}\\\mathsf P(S{=}D)&=\phantom{0.02}\\\mathsf P(S{=}H)&=\phantom{0.90}\\\mathsf P(S{=}M)&=\phantom{0.08}\end{align} $$

> Use Bayes formula to find the probability that a person selected at random has the serious disease, given that the test indicates that he or she does

Find $\mathsf P(S{=}D\mid T{=}D)$ using Bayes' formula. $$\mathsf P(S{=}D\mid T{=}D)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(T{=}D\mid S{=}D)~\mathsf P(S{=}D)}{\mathsf P(T{=}D)}$$

Also find $\mathsf P(T{=}D)$ using the Law of Total Probability. $$\mathsf P(T{=}D)=\phantom{\ldots}$$